# Serial port gets closed after what seems a random amount of time

Tags: c#, arduino, serial-port

I have a few serial devices that I need to identify. Each serial device is programed to send a ID string when "IDENT_DEVICE" is written. I am able to ID the device without problem but what seems to happen is that after 10-30 seconds the port is closed. I know its closed because I can click on the serial monitor button and the Arduino IDE will say something like port busy (which is what I would expect) but if I keep clicking the serial monitor button it will eventually open up.

So far I have tried adding an InfiniteTimeout which I was hoping was the key but sadly it was not

```
 private void Rescan()
        {

            
            string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();

            foreach (string port in ports)
            {
                string response = "";
                SerialPort sp = new SerialPort(port.ToString(), 115200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
                sp.Handshake = Handshake.None;

                
                sp.Open();
                sp.ReadTimeout = SerialPort.InfiniteTimeout;
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
                sp.Write("IDENT_DEVICE");

                Thread.Sleep(3000);  // give it some time to respond

                response = sp.ReadExisting();
                if (response.Contains("~"))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Found possible device");
                    isFound = true;
                    
                    string deviceName = response.Split('#')[1].Split('#')[0];

                    ConnectedDeviceType_TextBox.Text += deviceName;
                    
                }
                else
                {
                    sp.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: The code snippet you posted will open each port identified, try to read the device data, and continue, or close the connection. The loop is not going to keep the port open indefinitely. Since you are not using a "using" statement and only closing the port if response does not contain "~" the amount of time it takes to get released will appear random. You will need to change logic to keep the port open once identified, and best practices would be to dispose the port and cleanup manually. Thread.Sleep is also not great, I would suggest await Task.Delay() instead

Comment: Thanks, how exactly should I incorporate a using statement?

Comment: using (SerialPort sp = new SerialPort(port, 115200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One))
{... your code here ...} For more clarification, are you connecting to a single device, or multiple? Setting the isFound flag and populating a single Textbox makes me think single. You may want to do device discovery before opening a long lived connection to the port in question.

Comment: It could be as many as 1 single device all the up to 20 devices. isFound was a debug thing I added and wont be in the deployed code. So to give you an idea, I open each comport, and write "IDENT_DEVICE" the device that I have programed will respond to the "IDENT_DEVICE" string with a string "~EZS#GPU569#0.1.3#6251896H5R6L6S~" so then the code will see the "~" and  that will be a verified device... In another section of code I'll do further checking to make sure this is indeed the device I wanted to connect. If response.Contains = false then I just want to close that port and move on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are dropping all references to your serial port objects which then get cleared up by the garbage collector.

After every run of the foreach loop the "sp" object has no more references anywhere. You need to keep a reference to the relevant objects to keep them alive.

You need to do something like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    var portsWithDevice = new Dictionary<string, SerialPort>(); // use a dictionary to make adressing multiple ports easier

    private void Rescan()
    {            
        string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();

        foreach (string port in ports)
        {
            string response = "";
            SerialPort sp = new SerialPort(port, 115200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
            sp.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            
            sp.Open();
            sp.ReadTimeout = SerialPort.InfiniteTimeout;
            //Thread.Sleep(3000); // why is this here?
            sp.Write("IDENT_DEVICE");

            Thread.Sleep(3000);  // 3 seconds is super long

            response = sp.ReadExisting();
            if (response.Contains("~"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Found possible device"); // don't use MessageBox.Show(). It will block the thread which may cause problems.
                isFound = true; // you only have one isFound for possibly multiple devices. That might cause problems depending on what you do with it.
                
                string deviceName = response.Split('#')[1].Split('#')[0];

                ConnectedDeviceType_TextBox.Text += deviceName;
                portsWithDevice.Add(deviceName, sp); // add the ports you need to stay alive to a collection to keep a reference
            }
            else
            {
                sp.Close();
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

After running the Rescan() method the portsWithDevice dictionary will now contain all opened ports where a device was found. You can address them in there by using

```
portsWithDevice["port name as string"].DoStuff();
```

Since the dictionary holds references to all added ports they will not be cleared out by the garbage collector.

Comment: Thank you. This was the solution. I'll add that the 3 second thread sleep was needed to alow the device to wake up. If I write "IDENT_DEVICE" immediately after it is opened it sometimes spits back a partial response string so adding that sleep gives it time.